# Calculate Percentage of Total by Group in Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a query that returns results for multiple EVENT_IDs. I would like to calculate the percentage PPWAP of the total PPWAP of each EVENT_ID for each SELECTION-ID.

This is an example of the results for a single EVENT_ID:

[image]

Can anyone suggest how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean SELECTION_NAME? And can you please modify your question to show your expected output and expand the input data to include extra EVENT_ID and SELECTION_ID?

Comment: Thanks guys. These are great. And apologies, I meant SELECTION_NAME not SELECTION_ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be inclined to use `GROUP BY` and `JOIN` for this.  Your question is a bit unclear.  If you want the proportion by event:

```
select e.*, PPWAP / total_PPWAP as ratio
from tblEvent as e inner join
     (select event_id, sum(PPWAP) as total_PPWAP
      from tblEvent 
      group by event_id
     ) as ee
     on ee.event_id = e.event_id;
```

If you really want it by some unseen column such as `selection_id`, then you would use that for the `GROUP BY` and `JOIN`.

I often like correlated subqueries.  But in this case, it likely does more work than necessary, because it does the aggregation for each group multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you will need to use a subquery to get the total for each SELECTION, which you can then use to calculate the percentage of each row:

```
SELECT 
    E.EVENT_ID, 
    E.EVENT_NAME, 
    E.EVENT_DATE, 
    E.SELECTION_NAME, 
    E.PPWAP,
    (SELECT SUM(E1.PPWAP) FROM tblEvent AS E1 WHERE E1.EVENT_ID=E.EVENT_ID AND E1.EVENT_DATE=E.EVENT_DATE) AS TOTAL_PPWAP,
    E.PPWAP/TOTAL_PPWAP*100 AS PCT_PPWAP
FROM tblEvent AS E
```

This produces the following output:
[image]
You may need to change the fields used in the `WHERE` part of the subquery depending on exactly how you define the total to be calculated.

Regards,